# Using Makefile with Terraform and split project layout

Tags: makefile, terraform

I have a Terraform project layout that's similar to

```
stage
  └ Makefile
  └ terraform.tfvars
  └ vpc
  └ services
      └ frontend-app
      └ backend-app
          └ vars.tf
          └ outputs.tf
          └ main.tf
  └ data-storage
      └ mysql
      └ redis
```

Where the contents of `Makefile` are similar to

```
.PHONY: all plan apply destroy

all: plan

plan:
    terraform plan -var-file terraform.tfvars -out terraform.tfplan

apply:
    terraform apply -var-file terraform.tfvars

destroy:
    terraform plan -destroy -var-file terraform.tfvars -out terraform.tfplan
    terraform apply terraform.tfplan
```

As far as I understand it, `Terraform` will only run on templates in the current directory.  So I would need to `cd stage/services/backend-app` and run `terraform apply` there.

However I would like to be able to manage the whole stack from the Makefile.  I have not seen a good clean way to pass arguments to `make`.

My goal is to have targets such as

```
make s3 plan # verify syntax
make s3 apply # apply plan
```

Unless there's a better way to run terraform from a parent directory?  Is there something similar to:

```
make all plan  # create stage plan
make all apply # apply stage plan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution could be to create a tmp folder on each run and use `terraform init ...` and `terraform get...`, like this (the example also shows the remote state management using partial configuration):

```
readonly orig_path=$(pwd) && \
mkdir tmp && \
cd tmp && \
terraform init -backend=true -backend-config="$tf_backend_config" -backend-config="key=${account}/${envir}/${project}.json" $project_path && \
terraform get $project_path && \
terraform apply && \
cd $orig_path && \
rm -fR tmp
```

Or maybe wrap the above into a shell script, and call it from make file under "apply" etc.

**-- adding this section to address a comment/question from Sam Hammamy --**

In general, with the way how the current versions of terraform processes projects, we do want to think ahead of time to how to structure our projects, and how to break them down into manageable still functional pieces. Which is why usually we break them into "foundational" projects like VPC, VPN, SecurityGroups, IAM-Policies, Bastions etc. vs. 'functional" like "db", "web-cluster" etc. We usually run/deploy/modify the "fundamental" pieces once or occasionally, while the "functional" pieces we might re-deploy several times a day.

Which means that with the fragmenting of our IaC code like that, we also will end up of fragmenting of our remote state accordingly, and the execution of our project deployment as well.

For a project structure, which reflects that "philosophy" we usually end up with a project structure similar to this (common modules are not shown):

```
├── projects
│   └── application-name
│       ├── dev
│       │   ├── bastion
│       │   ├── db
│       │   ├── vpc
│       │   └── web-cluster
│       ├── prod
│       │   ├── bastion
│       │   ├── db
│       │   ├── vpc
│       │   └── web-cluster
│       └── backend.config
└── run-tf.sh
```

Where each project is a subfolder, and for each application_name/env/component = folder (i.e. dev/vpc) we added a placeholder backend configuration file: **backend.tf**:

```
terraform {
    backend "s3" {
    }
}
```

Where the folder content for each component will contain files similar to:

```
│       ├── prod
│       │   ├── vpc
│       │   │   ├── backend.tf
│       │   │   ├── main.tf
│       │   │   ├── outputs.tf
│       │   │   └── variables.tf
```

At "application_name/" or "application_name/env" level we added a backend.config file, with a content:

```
bucket     = "BUCKET_NAME"
region     = "region_name"
lock       = true
lock_table = "lock_table_name"
encrypt    = true
```

Our wrapper shell script expects parameters application-name, environment, component, and the actual terraform cmd to run.

The content of run-tf.sh script (simplified):

```
#!/bin/bash

application=$1
envir=$2
component=$3
cmd=$4

tf_backend_config="root_path/$application/$envir/$component/backend.config"

terraform init -backend=true -backend-config="$tf_backend_config" -backend-config="key=tfstate/${application}/${envir}/${component}.json" 

terraform get

terraform $cmd
```

Here is how a typical run-tf.sh invocation looks like (to be executed from Makefile):

```
$ run-tf.sh application_name dev vpc plan

$ run-tf.sh application_name prod bastion apply
```

Comment: How will the remote state contain all of the components this way? The remote state is updated after each `terraform apply`.  So if you're saving $project_path, how are subdirectories included into this state?

Comment: I added a new section above to expand the example with the details, explaining the management of the remote state per sub-projects, and how the folder structure corresponds to projects structure - both semantics and physical mapping. Hope that helps.

Comment: That clears up my question.  I thought you had a trick for combining states other the `outputs.tf` which I was currently employing.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

We use shell scripts to handle this exact use case which more nicely handles `cd`ing around.

However you can set Make variables by either using environment variables or setting it directly on the command line following the target like this:

```
make target FOO=bar
```

So in your case you might want something like:

```
ifndef LOCATION
$(error LOCATION is not set)
endif

.PHONY: all plan apply destroy

all: plan

plan:
    cd $(LOCATION) && \
    terraform plan -var-file terraform.tfvars -out terraform.tfplan

apply:
    cd $(LOCATION) && \
    terraform apply -var-file terraform.tfvars

destroy:
    cd $(LOCATION) && \
    terraform plan -destroy -var-file terraform.tfvars -out terraform.tfplan
    terraform apply terraform.tfplan
```

I'd probably be inclined to have a target that runs `terraform get` and also configures remote state as well but that should be trivial to set now.